# WildFly 9 Access Logging

Tags: wildfly, access-log, wildfly-9

I am trying to set up access logging using WildFly 9 in Domain mode. I have found a few resources which suggest using something like this in the domain.xml file:

```
 <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
     <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
     <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
     <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
     <access-log pattern="%A%t%h%l%u%r%s%b%T%I" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access" suffix=".log"/>
 </host>
```

I then restarted wildfly, but no logging is occurring and there are no errors in the wildfly start up, so I am just banging my head against the wall. I would really appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Also is there a way to register access logging using the cli in domain mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a way to add all resources in CLI for both domain mode and standalone. It's possible you're editing the wrong profile in the XML. Regardless using CLI is the preferred solution.

The first thing you need to know is which profile you're running under. You can determine by the server-group(s) running.

```
[domain@localhost:9990 /] /server-group=*:read-attribute(name=profile)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [
        {
            "address" => [("server-group" => "main-server-group")],
            "outcome" => "success",
            "result" => "full"
        },
        {
            "address" => [("server-group" => "other-server-group")],
            "outcome" => "success",
            "result" => "full-ha"
        }
    ]
}
```

We'll assume here we're using the `main-server-group`. You then need to add the [`access-log` setting](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/9.0.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/server/host/setting/access-log/index.html) to the `undertow` subsystem.

```
/profile=full/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=access-log:add(pattern="%A%t%h%l%u%r%s%b%T%I", directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}", prefix=access, suffix=".log")
```

This will add access logging to all servers in that server-group. You will need to access a server via a web request before the log will be created. No restart or reload is required either.

One extra note too you can see what settings are available to the `setting` resource in undertow with the following command.

```
/profile=full/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=*:read-resource-description
```

Comment: Im getting 'Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [("server-group" => "*")]"
'

Comment: What version of WildFly? Also are you using domain mode?

Comment: Wildfly 10.1 Final, and no, in standalone mode.

Comment: That is why. You don't need the first command and you leave the `profile=full` off the other two commands.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to log time taken to process the request, in seconds (format attribute %T) you should add additional parameter:

```
/profile=full/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=record-request-start-time,value=true)
```